# Transformar cadena de texto con signo en número

Tags: python

me gustaría convertir un *string* en un *float* con signo tanto positivo como negativo para representarlos en una gráfica.
Gracias.

Comment: La cadena de texto a la que quería referirme sería del estilo (-2,23), con los decimales separados por coma. Gracias.

Comment: La han cerrado haciendo referencia a una respuesta que no responde al problema planteado. Lo que se quiere convertir es un string con coma decimal. Si se aplica float('-3,5') siguiendo lo indicado en la respuesta de la referencia dará error.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich. La respuesta señalada resuelve el problema de convertir string a float (que no debería ser pregunta en primer lugar). Lo que queda es trivial: sustituir una coma por un punto.

Comment: No necesariamente es trivial porque lo puedes hacer con `locale` y bno entrarias a sustituciones. Bueno, a lo que iba era que habian formas de hacerlo sin recurrir a sustituciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplemente usar `float`:

```
x = "-2.5"
float(x)
```

Veo que también te interesa para los casos en los que el número usa una coma como separador decimal. Previo al paso explicado, puedes sustituir la coma con un punto y luego transformarlo en float:

```
x = "-2,5"
x = x.replace(",", ".")  # x ahora sería "2.5"
float(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

No tengo bastante reputación para añadir un comentario, por lo que me veo a completar la respuesta de [@xgsktx][1] en una nueva respuesta :

```
x = "-2.5O"
y = float(x)
```

Ese código generaría una excepción que habría que tratar (como norma general):

```
x = "2.5O"  # no es un cero sino una letra O mayúscula
try:
    y = float(x)
except ValueError:
    print(f"El valor {x} no se ha podido convertir a float")
```

También podemos hacer una función que filtre la excepción, pero puede que no sea tan buena idea, porque nos obliga a comprobar el resultado

```
def str2float(cadena: str) -> float:
    """Convierte cadena en un float y lo devuelve. En caso de error, devuelve None"""
    
    resultado = None
    try:
        resultado = float(cadena)
    except ValueError:
        # Quizá queremos poner aquí algún mensaje
        pass

    return resultado

x = "2.5O"  # no es un cero sino una letra O mayúscula
y = str2float(x)
if y is None:
    print(f"No se puede convertir {x} en float")
else:
    print(f"El valor float de {x} es {y}")
```

Si queremos que la función entienda los "floats" con ","

```
def str2float(cadena: str) -> float:
    """Convierte cadena en un float y lo devuelve. En caso de error, devuelve None"""

    resultado = None
    
    candidato = cadena.replace(',', '.')  # cambiar coma por punto
    
    try:
        resultado = float(candidato)
    except ValueError:
        # Quizá queremos poner aquí algún mensaje de log
        pass

    return resultado
    
x = "3,1416"
y = str2float(x)
if y is None:
    print(f"No se puede convertir {x} en float")
else:
    print(f"El valor float de {x} es {y}")
```

La salida de todo esto sería:

`El valor 2.5O no se ha podido convertir a float`
`No se puede convertir 2.5O en float`
`El valor float de 3,1416 es 3.1416`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: +1 por una respuesta bien explicada, documentada y comprobada. Vas bien.

Answer (score 1):

Convertir una cadena a número es tan simple como usar las función float(str), sto te va a dar como resultado un dato de tipo float.
Si lo quieres entero pues usa int(str).

Comment: En el caso de que mi número esté utilizando coma en lugar de punto para separar la parte decimal (2,23), ¿ hay alguna función posible?